# Negative margin affects the absolute positioned div on same level

Tags: css, html, css-position, absolute

I have a `#left`, absolute positioned div and 2 other divs on the right side. When I add margin to the `#top` div on the right side it affects the `#left` div too. I know there's a margin collapse stuff but is it affects the `position:absolute` too?

The code is really simple, nothing special, but I can't find the solution.

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:gray;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:100px;
}

#left {
    background:pink;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    left:-100px;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}

#right {
    background:red;
}

#top {
    background:green;
    height:26px;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9thvLfe0/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to #top :

```
float:right;
width:100%;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr6y5uec/)

Answer (score 0):

Just give the margin to top and give negative margin same to left.

Comment: Yes, I will if I can't find an other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that your #wrapper is relative and the #left is absolute.
By inheritance, #top and #right are also relative. So, adding a negative margin to top in these conditions, it's adding it to #wrapper.

You could change #wrapper to position "fixed" but you would have to manually set the margin/padding to #hide-top because as it is, he will be hidden under #wrapper. Unless you set it like that :

```
#hide-top {
    position: relative;
    top: 400px;
}
```

Yet, my solution wasn't to change your CSS but your JQuery. You could just hide #top with the hide() function. See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/3rmd24xo/) for example ;).

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to slide off the div from the screen with animation.(SlideUp is not the perfect solution for me) Please check the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/9thvLfe0/2/